# My App Force closes on onRequestPermissionResult when i try to add sth to the program

Tags: java, android

I'm sorry if its not specific enough as I've no idea how to describe this problem.
I am new to android and have been trying out various programs till i face this issue where I am kind of merging my app than generates gps on a single click to my another app which sort of already have the onRequestPermissionResult as result I Tried many methods to fix it , end up rounding up it only occurs the error when i try to change this.

Original app

```html
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                if (PermissionUtils.permissionGranted(requestCode, CAMERA_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST, grantResults)) {
                    startCamera();
                }
    }
```

Codde from GPS I'm trying to merge in

```html
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    configureButton();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

I do not know much about programming yet and still learning so I would be grateful if someone would teach me how to handle this kind of situation when i face it again. Thanks in advance ~

Comment: what do you exactly want ? Want to know how to deal with camera using run time permissions ?

Comment: I am able to run both different project successfully , but after merging it, I wan to know how to allow both the configure button and start camera in that part to keep the program running.

Comment: you mean you want camera and locations to be used in the same page where you need to ask permission for both location and camera????